# Highcharts python

Tags: python, highcharts

I have a python code:

```
    from highcharts_core.chart import Chart
        
    Chart.from_pandas(load_pickle_p, property_map={
        'x': 'Date',
        'y': 'Power'
    }, series_type='area', chart_kwargs={'container': 'container',
        'variable_name': 'myChart'}, series_kwargs={'xAxis': [{'type':     'datetime'}]}).to_js_literal('my_js_literal.js')
```

my_js_literal.js after run python code is:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container',
    {
      series: [{
      data: [[1697241600000.0,
    -34.3736262321],
    [1697260980000.0,
    -34.1538462639],
    [1697265960000.0,
    -33.8439569473],
    [1697317320000.0,
    -32 4904761314]],
  name: 'Power',
  type: 'area'
}]
},
);
});
```

and charts in browser x axis draw in milliseconds not in datetime format

how to set x axis type to datetime before i call def .to_js_literal ?

i try set  series_kwargs, options_kwargschart_kwargs
with dict {'xAxis': [{'type': 'datetime'}]}
and xAxis in my_js_literal.js not included

Whats wrong i do and how solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

i solve my problem

from documentation in https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.dateTimeLabelFormats.hour

we read xAxis but in python camelcase we need replace to "_a" as a result fields name must be x_axis, y_axis etc...
result working code is

```
chart = Chart.from_pandas(load_pickle_p, property_map={
    'x': 'Date',
    'y': 'Power'
}, series_type='area', options_kwargs={
    'title': {'text': 'Abrakadabra'},
    'x_axis': {
        'type': 'datetime',
        'dateTimeLabelFormats': {
            'hour': '%H:%M'
        }
    }
}, chart_kwargs={'container': 'container'})


chart.to_js_literal('my_js_literal.js')
```

and a result code file my_js_literal.js is set in

xAxis: {
dateTimeLabelFormats: {
hour: '%H:%M'
},
type: 'datetime'
}

Maybe its will come in handy